# Different data structures coming from a json

Tags: go

My question is,
 I have a JSON that returns me a list of objects.
But sometimes this list returns me a single object in case the det.

I try to use the pattern below

```
Det []struct {
                    NItem string `json:"-nItem"`
                    Prod  struct {
                        CProd    string `json:"cProd"`
                        CEST     string `json:"CEST"`
                        Cfop     string `json:"CFOP"`
                        UCom     string `json:"uCom"`
                        QCom     string `json:"qCom"`
                        IndTot   string `json:"indTot"`
                        VProd    string `json:"vProd"`
                        CEANTrib string `json:"cEANTrib"`
                        UTrib    string `json:"uTrib"`
                        NCM      string `json:"NCM"`
                        CEAN     string `json:"cEAN"`
                        XProd    string `json:"xProd"`
                        VUnCom   string `json:"vUnCom"`
                        QTrib    string `json:"qTrib"`
                        VUnTrib  string `json:"vUnTrib"`
                    } `json:"prod"`
                    Imposto struct {
                        VTotTrib string `json:"vTotTrib"`
                        ICMS     struct {
                            ICMS00 struct {
                                Orig  string `json:"orig"`
                                CST   string `json:"CST"`
                                ModBC string `json:"modBC"`
                                VBC   string `json:"vBC"`
                                PICMS string `json:"pICMS"`
                                VICMS string `json:"     vICMS"`
                            } `json:"ICMS00"`
                        } `json:"ICMS"`
                        IPI struct {
                            CEnq    string `json:"cEnq"`
                            IPITrib struct {
                                CST  string `json:"CST"`
                                VBC  string `json:"vBC"`
                                PIPI string `json:"pIPI"`
                                VIPI string `json:"vIPI"`
                            } `json:"IPITrib"`
                        } `json:"IPI"`
                        PIS struct {
                            PISAliq struct {
                                CST  string `json:"CST"`
                                VBC  string `json:"vBC"`
                                PPIS string `json:"pPIS"`
                                VPIS string `json:"vPIS"`
                            } `json:"PISAliq"`
                        } `json:"PIS"`
                        COFINS struct {
                            COFINSAliq struct {
                                CST     string `json:"CST     "`
                                VBC     string `json:"vBC"`
                                PCOFINS string `json:"pCOFINS"`
                                VCOFINS string `json:"vCOFINS"`
                            } `json:"COFINSAliq"`
                        } `json:"COFINS"`
                    } `json:"imposto"`
                } `json:"det"`
```

but works perfectly, but when the det object receives only element the unmarshal does not work, only works if I remove the slice of struct like that

```
Det struct {
                    NItem string `json:"-nItem"`
                    Prod  struct {
                        CProd    string `json:"cProd"`
                        CEST     string `json:"CEST"`
                        Cfop     string `json:"CFOP"`
                        UCom     string `json:"uCom"`
                        QCom     string `json:"qCom"`
                        IndTot   string `json:"indTot"`
                        VProd    string `json:"vProd"`
                        CEANTrib string `json:"cEANTrib"`
                        UTrib    string `json:"uTrib"`
                        NCM      string `json:"NCM"`
                        CEAN     string `json:"cE
```

The whole structure looks like this.

`SomeStruct struct {
                ID  string json:"-Id"
                Ide struct {...} json:"ide"
                Total struct {
                    ICMSTot struct {...} json:"ICMSTot"
                } json:"total"
                Cobr struct { Dup struct {....} json:"dup" } json:"cobr"
                Versao string json:"-versao"
                Emit   struct { ... } json:"enderEmit"
                Det []struct {
                    NItem string json:"-nItem"
                    Prod  struct {
                        CProd    string json:"cProd"
                        CEST     string json:"CEST"
                        Cfop     string json:"CFOP"
                        UCom     string json:"uCom"
                        QCom     string json:"qCom"
                        IndTot   string json:"indTot"
                        VProd    string json:"vProd"
                        CEANTrib string json:"cEANTrib"
                        UTrib    string json:"uTrib"
                        NCM      string json:"NCM"
                        CEAN     string json:"     cEAN"
                        XProd    string json:"xProd"
                        VUnCom   string json:"vUnCom"
                        QTrib    string json:"qTrib"
                        VUnTrib  string json:"vUnTrib"
                    } json:"prod"`

Comment: You can try unmarshaling into a slice, and if you get an error, try unmarshaling into a struct.

Comment: I will try it ! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode the JSON as a slice if the first non-whitespace byte in the input is `[`. Otherwise, decode the JSON as a struct.

```
func decode(data []byte) ([]Det, error) {
    data = bytes.TrimSpace(data)
    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("empty")
    }
    if data[0] == '[' {
        var v []Det
        err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
        return v, err
    }
    var v [1]Det
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v[0])
    return v[:], err
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/mzehQnfwKDJ)

If the `Det` value is a member of a struct, then use [RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to capture the JSON and then use the function above.

```
 type SomeStruct struct {
    ....
    DetRaw json.RawMessage `json:"Det"`
    Det []Det `json:"-"`
    ....
}

var v SomeStruct
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
v.Det, err = decode([]byte(v.DetRaw))
if err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

Comment: OK this helped a lot but how to do this being that the json object has more fields the det is just a piece of JSON.

Comment: @IgorGuedesRodrigues Use json.RawMessage. See updated answer.